# Angular: Overload constructor DRY

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

Let's say we have the following two components:

```
export class HeroComponent {
  constructor(
    public service1: Service1,
    public service2: Service2,
 ) {
   // do something
 }
}

export class AdvancedHeroComponent extends HeroComponent {
  constructor(
    public service1: Service1,
    public service2: Service2
  ) {
    super(service1, service2);
    // do something more
  }
}
```

Is there any way to tell to tell Angular that the paramaters for the constructors of the base and the extension class are the same except copy pasting them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**The solution below works for TS in general, but not for Angular, which has extra compiler transforms on top of TS**

You can use rest and spread in function parameters/arguments to get this to work. You will also need the `Parameters` predefined type to extract the original parameter types from the base constructor:

```
export class HeroComponent {
  constructor(
    public service1: Service1,
    public service2: Service2,
 ) {
   // do something
 }
}

export class AdvancedHeroComponent extends HeroComponent {
  constructor(
    ...p: ConstructorParameters<typeof HeroComponent>
  ) {
    super(...p);
    // do something more
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AlhQgYQgFtIA7YU+AbwCg5EJS0YoBXBGaACjvrjFYAjJAEsEcNLgBuY4AEYAXHADK02XIA0vegOFiJahMABMS1VBlHjWuAEo4tPgHoncACYQJxYDAAWI0gBzOgBfGjCaUEhYRFQMOABBNykUUiM3HDxCEkYKeFAYCjdMTIJiMjyHXgRGZjYObm04ADpWsCVCJhZ2TigABRQoFCIfXDQAHhgATzBgCAAzbFwynPJKAD5ee0c+NFZZqC5W5rBbAG4ml3dPNG8-AMC4ImhgXjCQoA)

**Note** You DONT need the `public` modifier in the derived type parameters. The field is already declared on the base type so the extra `public` will just re-declare the field. This might actually cause issues for `private` or `protected` fields.

Comment: This looks like a clean solution. I can't recreate a working version in Stackblitz. I was experimentng with adding an additional service to my advanced hero, but the ConstructorParameters can't be resolved with or without the additional service. What am I missing? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-61qwry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadvanced-hero%2Fadvanced-hero.component.ts

Comment: @KurtHamilton Well... this is not ideal.. Angular has an extra transform on top of TS. that extra transform is responsible for ensuring correct parameter injection .. and it does not support this trick  apparently . I would classify this as a bug in angular IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract "do something more" logic and override in the child class:

```
export class HeroComponent {
  constructor(
    public service1: Service1,
    public service2: Service2,
 ) {
   // do something
   this.doSomethingMore();
 }

  protected doSomethingMore() {}
}
```

```
export class AdvancedHeroComponent extends HeroComponent {
    // no explicit constructor definition

    protected doSomethingMore() {
        console.log('actually doing something more');
    }
}
```